# How to return char (*)[6] in c?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

I want to sort array of string, which is array of array of characters in c, in alphabetical order.Here is the body of my function :-

```
char (*)[6] sort_strings ( char (*sptr) [6])
{

     //code.
     //return a pointer of type char (*)[6].

}
```

But this type of return type is not recognized by the compiler.It gives error saying:-

> expected identifier or '(' before ')' token

So how do i return a pointer of type char (*)[6]? I have another question in mind, firstly see the `main()` as follows:-

```
int main(){

    char names[5][6] = {

            "tom",
            "joe",
            "adam"
    };

    char (*result)[6] = sort_strings (names);

    //code for printing the result goes here.

    return 0;
}
```

So my next question is that when i call `sort strings (names)` compiler is also giving me warning :-

> initializing makes pointer from integer without a cast

So my questions are :-

**1.** How to return char(*)[6] from a function?

**2.** Why the compiler giving me warning when i call this function?

I am running this code on code blocks on windows.

Comment: @Transcendental is it equivalent to char(/*)[6].i think that this notation will ultimately decay into char(/*)[6], am i write?

Comment: Note that `char (*)[6]` is *not* a pointer to an array of strings.

Comment: @Rouftantical I'm not quite sure about that, but why don't you just pass the array to the function,  and just sort it inside. There's really no need to return 2D array of characters, unless you want it that  way.

Comment: @immibis but it is a pointer to array of 6 characters.

Comment: immibis beat me to the answer, but while testing I noticed that the name `clarke` actually needs 7 char's, not 6, due to the NUL terminator.

Comment: @user3386109 yes thanks for your feedback, i have typed names here randomly, so i am sorry for that.

Comment: @Transcendental it's not working

Comment: In short, you never do this way!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch why not i am only passing a pointer to array of 6 char.What is the problem in my approach.

Comment: Why the 6? Hard coding such a size is very bad practice!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am just asking a small instance of a big problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Function declarations look like variable declarations, except that the variable name is replaced by the function name and arguments. So:

```
// asdf is a pointer to an array of 6 chars
char (*asdf)[6];

// sort_strings is a function returning a pointer to an array of 6 chars
// (and with an argument which is a pointer to an array of 6 chars)
char (*sort_strings ( char (*sptr)[6] )) [6];
```

Comment: please explain more about your last notation.

Comment: and why the function body is not accepted by the compiler, in terms of syntax?

Comment: Function declartation works as you suggested but compiler is giving same error.Please explain in detail what is happening.

Comment: oh sorry! that's my bad! it works, but please it will be more helpful if you can explain me in some detail, how it works because the function declaration you written works very well but it seems tricky.

Comment: The explanation is simple: this is how the syntax of C is defined.

Comment: However, coding this way is not genuine C programming style. No one would do that in practice.

Comment: @Rouftantical It's the same as the first one, but with `asdf` replaced by `sort_strings(char (*sptr)[6])`

Comment: @immibis; How would you access the elements through `char (*sort_strings ( char (*sptr)[6] )) [6];` ?

Comment: @haccks What? It doesn't make sense to "access the elements of a function". If you mean the return value, then `char (*result)[6] = sort_strings(&your_array));` and `(*result)[0]` through `(*result)[5]`. (Also, since it ends with a semicolon, the line I posted is a declaration not a definition)

Answer (score 0):

If you insist of sorting an array of specifically 6 strings, you could pack it in some `struct` like

```
 struct sixstrings_st {
    char* ptrarr[6];
 };
```

However, you probably want to sort an arbitrary number of strings. Then you either pass that number as another formal argument (you could also have some other *convention* like storing the size of the array in some global, but that is ugly):

```
 void sort_strings (char**arrptr, unsigned siz);
```

or you may use [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member).

BTW, don't reinvent sorting, use [qsort(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html)

Also, for readability purposes you generally don't want to have complex looking types. Use `typedef`, and define as much as `struct` (possibly with `union`-s) as needed.

Be careful about using arrays. In many occasions (notably argument passing to functions) an array is *decayed* into a pointer (notice that processors usually don't deal with entire arrays at once in a single machine instruction). And a function cannot really return an array, just a pointer (or some `struct`).

In C programming, it is common to have functions returning *scalar* data (e.g. an integer, or some pointer). Returning a `struct` is not very common (contrarily to C++, where returning a `class` instance is usual). When you do return a `struct` you usually want it to be "small enough" (otherwise the function return has conceptually to copy a lot of bytes). BTW, some [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)-s may have specific rules for returning a `struct` of two scalar elements. For [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf) on Linux, `struct` with two integers or two pointers are returned thru two machine registers.

Often, functions are returning pointers (perhaps obtained by `malloc` and filled in the function), and you should define a convention and document what should be done with the returned pointer, in particular who has the responsibility to `free` it and how. A common idiom in C programming is to define creating functions `foo_create` which are allocating a complex data structure `struct foo_st` (often by calling `malloc` for some `struct` and other creating functions for its components) and returning a pointer to it, and destroying function `foo_destroy` which are destroying such data structures (often by destroying components then calling `free` on the whole structure passed as a `struct foo_st*` pointer).

**In general, in *C* you want to avoid passing or returning *large* [data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure)** (such as big `struct`-s, arrays, `union`-s, ...) to and from functions (to avoid a lot of data to be copied, since C [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) is [call by value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value)). So you ***carefully* use pointers** to them instead: avoid [memory leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) and [memory corruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption). Hence you don't return a sorted array, but some pointer to it (and you document who should destroy that array, how and when) ... Read about [C dynamic memory allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) and even about [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) (at least to know the terminology, and basic techniques like [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting)).

At last, you usually don't want to hard code a size like your 6 in the source. You should want to handle arbitrarily (but reasonably) sized array of arbitrary strings. If you need to hard code a size, at least give it some readable name e.g. with `#define MY_WEIRD_SIZE 6` and code `MY_WEIRD_SIZE` instead of 6 at appropriate places...

Comment: yes char** do work but why my notation is not working

Comment: Because C is designed that way (because historically C was designed to be close to the hardware, and hardware does not process entire arrays in a single machine instruction). With C++ you could have used `std::array`

Comment: in the struct case it would be nice to return pointer to  struct.

Comment: Not always, C permit to return a  `struct` and there are many useful cases for that!

Comment: please if you can explain me the other answer

Comment: i am saying it as an alternative to approach in which we have to copy a lot of bytes.